# Only compare YYYY-MM part of date using Springboot and MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, jdbc

I am facing issue with mongoDb date fields.
I have one column in MongoDB collect which is date type. Which store whole date in ISO format.
As like below.

**`2020-05-13T14:00:00.000`**

Now from my api i am passing **`2020-05`** means **`YYYY-MM`** and i want to fetch all records with **`2020-05`** value in db.

I had tried with multiple option as below.

```
Date mydate=new Date();
Criteria criterid = Criteria
                .where("date").is(mydate)
```

I have below data in DB

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Name           |     ID           |  Date            |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          A          |         1        |2020-05-13T14:00:00|
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          B          |         2        |2020-12-31T14:00:00|
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          C          |         3        |2020-07-17T14:00:00|
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          D          |         4        |2020-05-29T14:00:00|
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|

enter code here
```

And if i will pass "2020-05" then it should returns

```
|---------------------|------------------|--------------------|
|      Name           |     ID           |  Date              |
|---------------------|------------------|--------------------|
|          A          |         1        |2020-05-13T14:00:00 |
|---------------------|------------------|--------------------|
|          D          |         4        |2020-05-29T14:00:00 |
|---------------------|------------------|--------------------|
```

Is there anything in mongoDb like [**`STR_TO_DATE()`**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp) in MySQL and [**`TO_DATE()`**](http://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-sql-server/to_date) in oracle`**.

I am trying to implement this in Spring boot application.

Try above query.

It will help you.

Comment: You are probably looking for a "between" query; if you use `LocalDateTime`, you can truncate to "month" and then add one month for bounds.

Comment: I am looking for exact match of **`YYYY-MM`**

Comment: **Never** store Date values as strings (applies to any database), use proper `Date` objects.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be this one:

```
db.collection.find({
   $expr: {
      $and: [
         { $eq: [{ $year: "$Date" }, 2020] },
         { $eq: [{ $month: "$Date" }, 5] }
      ]
   }
})
```